# Powerbi user's emailaddress

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to retrieve the logged in user's emailaddress and use that as part of a Query?

Our dataset contains data from different Organisations, we have a User table with a emailaddress and OrganisationId. If we can retrieve the logged in user then we can supply visualisations which filter the results based on the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... sort of.

For on-premise data sources you're connecting to via the Enterprise Gateway, only SQL Server Analysis Services consumes the user's UPN as EffectiveUserName for filtering (role-level in Multidimensional, role or row-level in Tabular using the USERNAME() as a filter.)

If you're importing your model up into PowerBI's cloud, then (*with a whole lot of caveats, definitely want to check all these out) using its [built in Row-Level Security](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-rls/)

When you create a new role, you could supply a DAX Filter of

User[EmailAddress] = USERNAME()

And when they log into PowerBI.com, all of their reports and datasets will be filtered appropriately.